# Jenkins-Maven-Tomcat-Nexus: compilation failed

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I implemented a java project with eclipse environment, i use maven to manage dependencies and inject some jars files in `TOMCAT_HOME/lib`.

When compile project in jenkins, compilation failed because missing of jars (which in tomcat/lib).

[image]

How can I solve this please?

Comment: Do you have the `javax.servlet dependency` in your `pom.xml`? If so, when you run Jenkins what maven command are you running? `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Yes i use _javax.servlet depedencies_.
In jenkins, not only _mvn clean install_ does not work ,_mvn clean compile_ failed also. As i said, i put some jars in tomcat/lib, for this reason jenkins ca't found it.

Comment: Please provide your `pom.xml` file. BTW: The issue you are seeing is exclusively a problem with your Maven build.

Comment: it's true that missing dependencies which generate compilation error not exist in pom.xml, but my question is _how make jenkins compile_ jee project with _jars dependencies in tomcat/lib (i mean not in pom.xml)_

Comment: when make tomcat/lib dependencies in pom.xml, jenkins compile project successfully, but i don't make those dependencies in pom.xml. How can solve that